# what are your favorite WPF controls?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, controls

So I've been developing in WPF on and off for a little while, and so far labored at making my controls look and behave sleek and intuitively from scratch. The only control suite I've checked out were Infragistics.

What are some cool/sleek/useful/time saving WPF controls you've come across of?

Comment: I'm personally very fond of the button control.

Comment: i don't think this subject was going to "lead to confrontation or argument", nor was i looking for specific answer. some people take them selves a little too seriously :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very nice and free set of controls for displaying graphs: DynamicDataDisplay. Two major flaws - lack of documentation and project seems to be abandoned. But being compared to other libraries I've tried it is the most perfectly constructed.

Answer (score 0):

We`re using the Telerik RadControls! Really good quality, good documentation, good forum support and really cool look and feel.

Check them out under --> http://demos.telerik.com/wpf/